# Print elements of a list but handle last element differently

Tags: prolog

I have written a predicate that prints out each element in the list except the last. The last element should be handled differently; it should print `LAST!` instead. This is what I have.

```
write_data([]).
write_data([X]) :-
    !, write('LAST!'), nl.
write_data([X | Rest]) :-
    write(x), nl,
    write_data(Rest).
```

Is there a better way? Is there a way to do this without the cut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the cut, by performing unification with a list that has at least two elements, like:

```
write_data([]).
write_data([_]) :-
    write('LAST!'),
    nl.
write_data([X|Rest]) :-
    Rest = [_|_],
    write(X), nl,
    write_data(Rest).
```

We can furthermore avoid the double unpacking with a helper predicate:

```
write_data([]).
write_data([H|T]) :-
    write_data(T, H).

write_data([], _) :-
    write('LAST!'), nl.
write_data([H|T], X) :-
    write(X), nl,
    write_data(T, H).
```

Comment: Another way to ensure that the list has at least two elements: `write_data([X1, X2|Rest]) :- ...`.

Comment: @Flux: yes, but then you have to "repack" the list in the recursion, which is not very efficient.

Comment: What is "unpacking" ? Your first solution seems best . Odd to have some of the work done in the entrance predikat that calls the recursiv predikat ; better to have all the work done in the recursiv predikat .

Comment: @Kintalken: a `[H|T]` is a functor, in order to get access to the parameters (`H` and `T`) it require some work. In the first example, the unpacking "per iteration" is more (it will usually take 3 unpackings per item in the list), whereas in the latter, that is only one per item in the list. In the Prolog libraries, one often see this kind of predicates that make it do less unpacking. Furthermore most prolog interpreters have some optimization on the first parameter, thus making it faster to match `[]`, vs `[_|_]`.

Comment: Sure conceptually what You say is true there is a recursive descent into the tree structure backing the list but! as a pragmatik issue the compiler does something much more efficient thus ``[H|T]`` becomes something (almost) like a C struct and the variables are (typically) indexed by number as slots . For example https://pasteboard.co/IGnIf1i.png .

Comment: @Kintalken: Of course it is a struct. But take a look at what the first program would look like, it matches against `[H|[]]`, and then against `[H|[_|_]]`, so that means we "unpack" a parameter of the functor, so there is an extra level of indirection. The *choice point* is one level deeper. So even "caching" the unpacking of the "top level" functor so to speak, has no effect on the indirect one. It is always surprising how easy it is to how easy it is to render smart optimizations in "vain".

Comment: fun discussion ! prompted me to discover swipl feature ``?- [library(vm)] . ?- vm_list(write_data) . ``

Comment: I took this discussion to a new question here :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828723/is-there-a-performance-benefit-for-the-second-of-these-solutions here :

Answer (score 1):

A common definition for a `last/2` predicate that provides access to the last element of a list is:

```
last([Head| Tail], Last) :-
    last(Tail, Head, Last).

last([], Last, Last).
last([Head| Tail], _, Last) :-
    last(Tail, Head, Last).
```

When called with the first argument bound to a closed list, the auxiliary predicate, `last/3`, avoids spurious choice-points assuming a Prolog system implementing, as common, first-argument indexing. Can you modify this predicate to do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb for cut removal is to note what was `true` in the clause that contains the cut , then make sure that is `false` in the other clause(s) .

Thus :

```
write_data([]).

write_data([X]) :-
    /*!,*/write('LAST!'), nl.

write_data([X | Rest]) :-
    dif(Rest,[]) , /**/
    write(x), nl,
    write_data(Rest).
```