# Is the second of these solutions more efficient?

Tags: prolog

Wondering if as a practical matter the post-compilation of the second solution below is more efficient .

first solution :

```
write_data([]).
write_data([_]) :-
    write('LAST!'),nl.
write_data([X|Rest]) :-
    Rest = [_|_],
    write(X),nl,
    write_data(Rest).
```

second solution :

```
write_data([]).
write_data([H|T]) :-
    write_data(T, H).

write_data([], _) :-
    write('LAST!'),nl.
write_data([H|T], X) :-
    write(X),nl,
    write_data(T, H).
```

some swipl magic :

```
?- [library(vm)] .

?- vm_list(write_data) , halt.
```

first solution swipl magic ::

```
========================================================================
write_data/1
========================================================================
   0 s_virgin
   1 i_exit
----------------------------------------
clause 1 (<clause>(0xb002c300)):
----------------------------------------
   0 h_nil
   1 i_exitfact
----------------------------------------
clause 2 (<clause>(0xb017da50)):
----------------------------------------
   0 h_list
   1 h_void
   2 h_nil
   3 h_pop
   4 i_enter
   5 b_atom('LAST!')
   7 i_call(write/1)
   9 i_depart(nl/0)
  11 i_exit
----------------------------------------
clause 3 (<clause>(0xb002bc80)):
----------------------------------------
   0 h_list_ff(1,2)
   3 i_enter
   4 b_unify_var(2)
   6 h_list
   7 h_pop
   8 b_unify_exit
   9 b_var1
  10 i_call(write/1)
  12 i_call(nl/0)
  14 b_var2
  15 i_depart(write_data/1)
  17 i_exit
```

second solution swipl magic ::

```
========================================================================
write_data/1
========================================================================
   0 s_virgin
   1 i_exit
----------------------------------------
clause 1 (<clause>(0xb272c300)):
----------------------------------------
   0 h_nil
   1 i_exitfact
----------------------------------------
clause 2 (<clause>(0xb27288c0)):
----------------------------------------
   0 h_list_ff(1,2)
   3 i_enter
   4 b_var2
   5 b_var1
   6 i_depart(write_data/2)
   8 i_exit
========================================================================
write_data/2
========================================================================
   0 s_virgin
   1 i_exit
----------------------------------------
clause 1 (<clause>(0xb2728920)):
----------------------------------------
   0 h_nil
   1 i_enter
   2 b_atom('LAST!')
   4 i_call(write/1)
   6 i_depart(nl/0)
   8 i_exit
----------------------------------------
clause 2 (<clause>(0xb272bc80)):
----------------------------------------
   0 h_list_ff(2,3)
   3 i_enter
   4 b_var1
   5 i_call(write/1)
   7 i_call(nl/0)
   9 b_var(3)
  11 b_var2
  12 i_depart(write_data/2)
  14 i_exit
```

Upon submission of the above stack overflow blocked with message "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." . HRM . Too much code in a question about computer programming ? (skratches virtual head) . Should I add some verbiage I heard about the new revolution "Bunch-Oriented" programming whilst around the water-cooler ?

Comment: Your first implementation has a an error. It won't write out the last element. Your `write_data([_]) :- ...` should be `write_data(X) :- write(X), nl,` and `write_data([]) :- write('LAST!'), nl.`.  I'd probably write, `write_data([X,X1|Rest]) :- write(X),nl, write_data([X1|Rest]).` for the last clause. Prolog does have some performance predicates you could use to determine, in each case, how many inferences are executed, etc. You could try those to get some information.

Comment: thanks @lurker . The code is someone else's from another discussion . Their intention was to capture the last element as a particular case .

Comment: The original version leaves a choice point open.  As to performance differences, there is hardly a difference.